# Pie graph drawn through Highchart not getting loaded in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, highcharts

We are using highchart API along with javascript to draw some graphs in our application. But in IE8 the window gets hanged as soon as i try to open graph. I don't know how to fix this.
in all other browsers i.e. chrome,mozilla its working fine.

---

The code goes like this

```
var chart=new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
     renderTo: container,
     plotBackgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
     plotBorderWidth: null,                 
     plotShadow: false,
     spacingTop: 0,
     spacingBottom: 0,
     animation: false
 },
 title: {
     useHTML: true,
     text: licenseText,
     style: {
         color: '#000000',
         fontSize: '12px',
         textDecoration: 'underline',
         fontWeight: 'bold'
     }
 },    
 plotOptions: {
     pie: {
         borderWidth: width,
         allowPointSelect: false,
         cursor: 'pointer',
         startAngle: 90,
         size: size,
         dataLabels: {
             enabled: showLabel,
             crop: true
         }
     }
 },
 series: [{
 name: 'Occurrences',
 type: 'pie',
 data:[]
 }]
});            
return chart;
```

Once we get this chart then we set data in it
chart.series[0].setData(numericDataSecondary);

How can i check object notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer is very strict with the object notation. please check your object notation, you may have kept a ',' for the last member of the object which is a mistake according to IE.

If possible please post your code, that will help us to know exactly what your problem is.

Comment: The code is slightly lengthy but i can try. It goes like-
 chart: {
         renderTo: container,
         plotBackgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
         plotBorderWidth: null,                 
         plotShadow: false,
         spacingTop: 0,
         spacingBottom: 0,
         animation: false
     },
     title: {
      useHTML: true,
         text: licenseText,
         style: {
             color: '#000000',
             fontSize: '12px',
             textDecoration: 'underline',
             fontWeight: 'bold'
         }
     },

Comment: when exactly is your browser hanging? when you open the chart with empty data or while you are adding the data using setData()